# Android canvas overlay camera

Tags: android, canvas, camera

Is there a way to overlay a camera preview on the android canvas? I have looked into drawing on images, but I have not found examples on drawing directly on the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you are building a custom camera extending the "SurfaceView" class, it already has a canvas on it.